# href = "#report-item" but not shown on url - how it works

Tags: html

I want to know how in [this web site](http://ikman.lk/en/bajaj-discover-2009-for-sale-matara-49), when I hover the mouse over report ad of the page, it show the link as `....com/***/***#report-item`, but when I click on it, it shows me a pop-up. but still the original URL is not changing to `....com/***/***#report-item`?

I checked the source of the page, and it shows the link code as: 
`<a href="#report-item" class="btn report" data-ui-nav="modal"><span><i class='ico-report'></i>Report Ad</span></a>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because they prevent the browser from doing what it is meant to do (default event).

Here is the JavaScript code for that:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

You can include that inside the element, something like

```
<a href="#hash-tag" onclick="function()">Link</a>
```

And inside the function, add that code. It would prevent the default function; that is to change the URL.

Maybe they're using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) for that because I can't see any sort of `onclick=""` inside the element. So what they might be doing would be this:

```
<a href="#report" class="btn report">Generate Report</a>
```

and the jQuery code would be as:

```
$('a.report').click(function () {
   event.preventDefault(); // prevent the default function of the hyperlink
   /* show the pop up */
});
```

This way, the website is preventing the default function and is using that link to do some other function.

Here is a fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/3zPd6/

### To get the Elements Attribute

To get the element's attribute in JavaScript you use the following code

```
document.getElementById("hyperlinkId").href;
```

This would get you the href of the hyperlink. And you can reference it in your call.

Comment: I think they are taking reference value href="#report" as the function. How can we get this value "report" as our DOM element in JavaScript?